# Overleaf add a file from another project, no compiling

Tags: overleaf

I copied a tex file from another project and it is strange that there is no compiling but only two buttons, refresh and download. How to compile the file like others? do I have to upload from local computer?

This is the steps:
Click upload button --> choose from another project --> choose a project and a file --> create[image: screen shot after the file is loaded.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use imported files as main files, only files that are editable in the project can be made main. The intended use of this feature is to bring over e.g. custom packages, bib files etc. across multiple projects.

Comment: As a side note, I pinged our content team to clarify this in our help pages.